# Laravel Mix / Webpack - Issue with loading jQuery

Tags: jquery, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I am trying to bundle assets with an older theme using Laravel Mix. Laravel mix complies without any errors however I am getting console errors when I view the website that indicate

```
//resources/js/theme-bundle.js

const jQuery = require('jquery');

window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;

//Theme Scripts
require('./theme/selectnav.js');
require('./theme/flexslider.js');
require('./theme/twitter.js');
require('./theme/tooltip.js');
require('./theme/effects.js');
require('./theme/fancybox.js');
require('./theme/carousel.js');
require('./theme/isotope.js');
require('./theme/jquery-easing-1.3.js');
require('./theme/greensock.js');
require('./theme/counterup.min.js');
require('./theme/waypoints.min.js');
require('./theme/owl.carousel.min.js');
require('./theme/custom.js');
```

Then in my package.json I have jquery defined:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.5",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.31",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "postcss": "^8.3.6",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.11",
    "sass-loader": "^11.0.1"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "gsap": "^3.10.0",
    "jquery": "1.11.1",
    "simplebar": "^5.3.5"
}
```

Lastly in my webpack.mix.js file I have:

```
/* 
    FRONT END Theme     
*/
mix
    .autoload({ 'jquery': ['$', 'window.jQuery', "jQuery", "window.$", "jquery", "window.jquery", 'global.jQuery', "global.$"] })
    .webpackConfig({
        resolve: {
            modules: [
                'node_modules'
            ],
            alias: {
                'TweenLite' : 'gsap/all'
            }
        }
    })
    .js('resources/js/theme-bundle.js', 'public/js/theme-bundle.js')
    .version();
```

I have looked up various solutions online, most of them seem to fix the issue by adding the autoload jquery line to the mix config, or by adding the lines I already have at the top of the theme-bundle.js file for referencing jquery. However neither of those things have worked for me.

I have tried with only the autoload, and with only lines at the top of the theme.bundle separately. I also tried aliasing jquery in the mix config, however it then seems to conflict with the other solutions I implemented, and when I remove those and only leave in the alias - then it seems to still not work.

I really don't understand what I could be doing wrong, when I inspect the bundle file - jquery is installed but for some reason even though mix complies and jquery is in the bundle, I am getting console errors:

```
$ is not a function at theme-bundle.js?id=a5d9f143522a9a93e7aa248048300a06:579:3
```

Answer (score 0):

Add jQuery in *resources/js/bootstrap.js*

```
try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
} catch (e) {}
```

And *app.js* to *webpack.js*:

```
mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js/app.js");
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I am not using bootstrap with this theme. I tried to use the try / catch at the top of my theme-bundle.js but it did not change anything. EDIT: I have an admin theme that is using bootstrap, but that is a different mix command I am using.

Comment: You could also try: 
`mix.autoload({ jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery'] });`

Comment: I already have that, I posted the code to my mix config in the question